# How to parse soap object data android?

Tags: android, parsing, soap

i am getting response from java web service using ksoap2, like

> CouponsListResponseParams{response=anyType{CouponId=333;
>   Coupon_name=REMEDY2; Coupon_amount=1500; Coupon_expiry_date=2012-05-02
>   00:00:00.0; }; response=anyType{CouponId=111; Coupon_name=REMEDY;
>   Coupon_amount=500; Coupon_expiry_date=2012-05-02 00:00:00.0; };
>   response=anyType{CouponId=222; Coupon_name=REMEDY2;
>   Coupon_amount=1000; Coupon_expiry_date=2012-05-02 00:00:00.0; }; }

please any one help me how to parse the data, i want to get copon id, coupon name etc..

please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit this link:- http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html

Answer (score 0):

If you make problem to read this type of complex data then you use HttpPost method to read SOAP service. HttpPost method return XML after read SOAP service.

You can able to parse easily this return XML by using XML DOM parse.